# disabling bottom toolbar tinymce

Tags: jquery, mobile, tinymce

I know this sounds silly and the whole point of the tinymce editor is have the toolbar for the user to easily edit, but I need to disable that toolbar for mobile viewing mainly because the buttons are now just too small and difficult to use.

I have this code going on that is called only when the user is on a mobile device.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple",
        width: "800px",
        height: "400px",
        setup: function (e) {
          'validation stuff goes here'          
        }
    });
```

Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Try adding options `theme_advanced_buttons1: ''` (and also 2 and 3)

Comment: that works, but it gets rid of my height and width...and I kind of need those :)

Comment: oh...I'm dumb... I was adding it to the wrong textarea. Opps! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `theme_advanced_buttons1: ''` (empty string) to the `.init` options (as well as buttons2 and buttons3).